# Very high current frequency on transistor collector

Tags: homework, oscillation, multivibrator, astable

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDHwZG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am designing astable multivibrator for homework and I have calculated values for resistors and capacitors (hopefully right) but I just can't figure out why is current oscillating at very high freqency on transistor collector. Any advice?

Analysis:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "very high frequency"? What frequency did you expect to see? Do you understand which components control the oscillation frequency?

Comment: If you're talking about that high-frequency noise, that looks like simulator problems. You wouldn't see that in a real system--you'd see more consistent noise and probably less of it.

Comment: @Hearth Yes meant that noise. I need to fill a report about this simulation. Any way of reducing that noise?

Comment: This isn't something you'd file a report over--it's not a bug in the simulator, it's an unavoidable consequence of using ideal circuit elements and limited computing power. Adding in some parasitic elements should help, but I don't have the time or energy to figure out where they would help most.

Comment: Try a tiny RC across each transistor.

Comment: Change the integration method on your simulator. Most simulators allow you to choose, at least two different ones.  The one you are using is apparently not working with the models for the active devices.